# doctrine query builder not returning right response join with condition

Tags: symfony, doctrine, query-builder

Hi i have a logic problem in my query builder request, i need to get all project's elements by user id but if the project is public (visibility public) we get all the elements. its simple but the query does not return all projects.

Here is my repository code

```
public function getAllIdsByUserIdAndProjectIdQueryBuilder($id_user, $id_project)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('element')
            ->select('element.id')
            ->innerJoin('element.project', 'project','with','project.visibility=:visibility')
            ->innerJoin('project.usersShared', 'user')
            ->andWhere('project.id = :id_project')
            ->andWhere('user.id = :id_user')
            ->setParameter(':id_user', $id_user)
            ->setParameter(':id_project', $id_project);
            ->setParameter(':visibility', 'PUBLIC');

    return $qb;
}
```

Comment: Try thinking on the raw SQL query that you'd write for this. To get all projects, would you start your query from the element table?

Comment: yes its the element repository because i need to get the elements not the projects, (one project have many elements)

Comment: Then I think I didn't quite get the question. You are saying that you expect all projects back, but you're filtering on them, so you only will get those elements belonging to a project with public visibility.

Comment: i need all the elements that belong to a public project and all the elements that belong to a project shared by a user (user project have many to many relation)

Comment: i pass a project id and a user id param if the project is public return all elements else look after user id if its a shared project return the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i got it its an orX condition

```
 public function getAllIdsByUserIdAndProjectIdQueryBuilder($id_user, $id_project)
{   
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('element')
            ->select('element.id')
            ->innerJoin('element.project', 'project')
            ->leftJoin('project.usersShared', 'user')
            ->andWhere('project.id = :id_workspace');

    $qb->andWhere(
            $qb->expr()->orX(
                    $qb->expr()->eq('user.id', ':id_user'),
                    $qb->expr()->eq('project.visibility', ':public_visibility')
                    )
            )                
            ->setParameter(':id_user', $id_user)
            ->setParameter(':public_visibility', 'PUBLIC')
            ->setParameter(':id_project', $id_project);

    return $qb;
}
```